# Как отключить отладку в приложении?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Работаю в Android Studio. Надо отключить отладку в Android приложении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лично для меня <a href="http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php">эта</a> статья помогла

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.apk подписывайте релизным, а не debug ключом .

**Build -> Generate Signed APK** и подписывайте своим релизным ключом.